# why am i getting a segmentation fault in this assembly print function

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86

So i am trying to make a simple assembly program, and i am getting a seg fault, the print function does indeed print out what i want, but than it crashes.

test.s:

```
.global _start

msg1:
        .string "Hello, World!\n"
msg2:
        .string "Goodbye, World !\n"

_start:
        PUSHQ   %rbp
        MOVQ    %rsp, %rbp
        MOVQ    $msg1, %rax
        CALL    print
        MOVQ    $msg2, %rax
        CALL    print
        POPQ    %rbp
        RET

# void print(char * x[%rax])
print:
print_init:
        PUSHQ   %rbp
        MOVQ    %rsp, %rbp
        SUBQ    $32,  %rsp
        MOVQ    %rax, -32(%rbp)
print_loop:
        MOVL    $1, %edx
        MOVL    -32(%rbp), %ecx
        CMPB    $0, (%ecx)
        JE      print_exit
        MOVL    $1,   %ebx
        MOVL    $4,   %eax
        INT     $0x80
        ADDQ    $1, -32(%rbp)
        JMP     print_loop
print_exit:
        POPQ    %rbp
        RET
```

thanks for helping guys!

Comment: `CMPB    $0, (%ecx)` you know you're writing 64-bit code, right?  You stored a 64-bit pointer to the stack (for no apparent reason), then reloaded and dereffed the low 32 bits.  Also you're trying to use `int $0x80` in 64-bit code, so that might crash e.g. if you're on WSL1 on Windows.  ([What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)).

Comment: @PeterCordes alright thanks! let me try to fix this...
edit: wait, but if this was the error, wouldn't it crash before even printing anything?

Comment: And then you try to `ret` from `_start` which isn't function: RSP on process entry doesn't point at a return address.

Comment: The `(%ecx)` probably isn't actually the cause of the segfault: if the program linked and ran at all, then `MOVQ    $msg1, %rax` was able to represent the absolute address as a signed 32-bit immediate, so truncating it shouldn't actually change it.  A 32-bit address-size override is inefficient but probably didn't cause the crash.  Use a debugger to see exactly what happened.  (And write 32-bit code if you want to copy/paste from 32-bit examples that use int 0x80 instead of syscall.

Comment: @PeterCordes alright thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you're right, it would crash before printing anything if that was the problem.  I initially just read the question title, which said it crashed **in** the print function.  (i.e. before print itself even returns).  So your question title doesn't match what you said in the question body.

Comment: Err wait, looks like you don't restore RSP at the bottom of `print`, so it probably crashes there when you `ret` with RSP pointing at garbage instead of its return address.  There's no reason to do anything with RSP or RBP in `print`, just registers.  Also, it would be *much* more efficient to make one system call with the total length of the string, instead of `write(1, ptr, 1)` for every char separately, so sink the system call out of the loop and just do a strlen loop.